# Bash counting directories, subdirectories and files

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, count, directory

I have had a look at all the other answers on stack overflow and have spent all day on this.

The first thing I am trying to do is count all the directories/subdirectories in a the specified directory, which ideally should be pretty simple. To begin with I ask the user to enter the directory name.

```
#Choosing directory
echo "Please type in directory cd: [directory name]"
read dirname
cd $dirname
echo "Entering directory"
```

This is working fine. Next there are two methods I have tried for finding the number of folders.

The directory I am testing has 6 directories/subdirectories in total within it and 3 files.

**The first method** is using 'find' and 'wc' on its own, however this outputs a string "         7" with spaces in front, I do not want to count the directory that we have selected. I also can't subtract one from this value if I set it as a variable as it is a string with spaces at the front.

```
direnum=`find . -type d | wc -l`
echo "$direnum"
```

(result = 7)(require result = 6)

**The second method** is using a 'for loop' along with 'find' and 'wc'. This method works fine, but is extremely slow when there is many files.

```
i=0
for d in `find . -type d` 
do
   i=`expr $i + 1`
done

#dont include the directory currently in
i=`expr $i - 1`

#output results
echo "Directories: $i"
```

(result = 6)(require result = 6)

I also tried both methods with the files, however it does not output the correct number. I have 3 files within the directory, the first method outputs **5** and the second method outputs the result **8** not sure how this works.

**First method for file count**

```
#Check number of files in directory
filenum=`find . -type f | wc -l`
echo "$filenum"
```

Again results in a string "        5" with lots of spaces in front.

(result = 5)(require result = 3)

**Second method for file count**

```
#Check number of files in directory
j=0
for f in `find . -type f` 
do
    j=`expr $j + 1`
done
```

(result = 8)(require result = 3)

**If someone could put me on the right track it would be appreciated, I am not expecting a full solution, ideally I would like to figure it out on my own but I am probably doing something wrong.**

Comment: For a start, using `expr` child process is costly and unnecessary, just `(( i++ ))`.  Second, if you have a numeric string, make it an integer with `declare -i filename`, that ignores leading whitespace.

Comment: Cheers, i did try i++ and it was coming up with an error, obviously I was typing it the wrong way, that seems to work better. I will try the declare now for the other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my comment:

```
declare -i direnum
direnum=$(find . -type d|wc -l)
(( direnum-- ))
echo "$direnum"
```

By the way, notice that I am using `$( ... )` rather than back-ticks,  Back-ticks are considered bad practice and obsolete.

Comment: Yeah that works great, as for the file output showing the incorrect value, I was able to use an expression to subtract 1 off the total and it seems to be the correct output now. I'll read up on what you have done so I can fully understand what's happening. I can't upvote due to low reputation.

Thanks for the advice, I am only new to writing shell so you've helped me a lot. :)

Comment: @Lizzeiy: feel free to ask!

Comment: So I had a read. So first line you're declaring the variable as an integer. The second line, finding type directory within the current directory, wc -l is getting the number of lines, so how many directories/sub directories there are? Then finally (( direnum-- )) increment down?

Comment: Yup, you got it!  We usually say "decrement" rather than increment down.  Note you can do ordinary calculations, like `(( x = y * 42 ))`

Answer (score 0):

use mindepth

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

The command "tree" counts files and folder from a relative position

```
tree /path
```

will give you the information.
Do you need to use that info in other scripts?